# Change Unique value of different text boxes with same id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, css, sql

I Want to change value of text box(Bayno) to div id when drag and dropping it to another div. There are a few text boxes with same id(Bayno).
Value must be unique.
I want to pass a different value on multiple input boxes with same id.

I have tried following,

There are 12 div's like that and those are dropable.

```js
 $(function () {
        $(".square").draggable();
        
  $("#00").droppable({
                accept: "#car",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen")
      $('#bayno').val(this.id);

      
                },
                out: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).css("background-color", "")
      $('#bayno').val("12");
                }
        });
        
        });
```

```css
.square {
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
 
.squaredotted {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
<div id="00" style="width:auto;" class="squaredotted">WAITING BAY
<div id="car" class="square">AAA-1234
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="veno" id="veno" value="AAA-1234'">
<input type="hidden" name="bayno" id="bayno" value="00">
<button style="font-size:10px;"  type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
</div> 

</div> 
<div id="infoCars">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: id's should be unique. use class or name instead